# Android listview updating all items

Tags: android, listview, selection

I have a listview with a big list of items.
Now I have a common button "select all" on click of which should do some operation on each item in the list.

I saw the answers about overriding onscrollchanged. But I don't want user to do scrolling. Without that itself all items should be selected.

Currently I am iterating using listview.getcount, but this update for only current view group.

Comment: What exactly are you changing by clicking "select all" does it just check every rows checkbox or does it change the rows colour, or something else?

Comment: It checks all check boxes and add update the itemms to a database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have your custom `BaseAdapter` and overridden `getView(..)` method refreshes each view according to its state (checked/unchecked). If so, then you just need to make changes to the underlying data of this `ListAdapter` (let's say, iterate over the array which stores objects which are represented by this list and change some property of each object) and then call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method.

Comment: I have baseadpter and overriding getview . But notifyDataSetChanged doesnt seem to call the getview . So though my gebneric list is updated and notifyDataSetChanged is called , its not getting updated in the listview.

Comment: Actually, it should. Try [`notifyDataSetInvalidated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated()). Perhaps, you're doing something wrong, but it's hard to find out without seeing your `BaseAdapter` code.

Comment: Thank you ,notifyDataSetChanged is calling getview, sorry for my wrong info .. My logic was quite complicated as i had to support "select all" , clicking each row .. With all the answers here combined i somehow got it working .. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

What is working for me:

```
private void enableAllListItems() {
        for(int i=0;i<mCursorAdapter.getCount();i++)
            mCheckedPositions.set(i, true);
        mListView.invalidateViews();
    }
```

The import part is the "invalidateViews()", because you have to say the ListView that it's underlying data changed!

But I'm actually using my own Adapter so I overrode the getView()-Method. I'm not sure if it will work with the standard Adapters.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate it using the generic list that you use to populate the list. that would help you.

Comment: yeah that is one way and every time call listview.refreshdraw (). But that is making the logic very complicated. Is there an easier solution

Comment: you dont have to refresh it everytime call the operation that you want to do in the asyn task after performing the operations on all contents of the list call the method adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); the list will get refreshed

Comment: join the chat room Just for fun for a chat, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8044/just-for-fun

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
   private void SelectAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int count = this.mainListView.getAdapter().getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        this.mainListView.setItemChecked(i, true);

    }

}
```